# System Verilog typedef of typedef

Tags: enums, typedef, system-verilog

`typedef enum`s allow a convenient way to describe a set of name-value pairs. Is there a way to chain them to create deeper structures using enum at all levels?

For instance, I have the following:

```
typedef enum logic {ALPHA=0, BETA=1} a_t;
typedef enum logic {GAMMA=0, DELTA=1} b_t;
typedef enum logic {ZETA=0, ETA=1} c_t;
...
```

I want to create a variable `c` which is formed of `a_t` and `b_t`. Is this possible?

Something like:

```
a_t b_t c;
```

so at every dimension of `c`, I can have `enum`s.

EDIT: Some clarification - assume `a_t`, `b_t` and `c_t` are immutable as they are generated automatically. And there are hundreds of such different enums. I want to create bigger structures as I need because automatically generating all combinations of them would make the code too big and messy.

For instance, say my `a_t` describes number of masters and `b_t` describes number of slaves. I want to create a structure where I have this hierarchy in my signal, and at the same time allow `enum`s for them to allow easy of readability and use.

So, something like this:

```
c[MASTER_0][SLAVE_0]
c[MASTER_0][SLAVE_1]
c[MASTER_1][SLAVE_0]
c[MASTER_1][SLAVE_1]
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want `c` to be. You talk of "dimensions", which suggests you want an array. Can you declare `c` with a single `typedef`?

Comment: looks like you want your 'c' to be an enum which contains all 4 constants in it. It is **impossible**. you can create a struct though `struct  {a_t c1; b_t c2} c;`

Comment: The structures `a_t` and `b_t` are immutable. I want to know if there is a way to use two separate enums and create a third one using these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you perhaps referring to an [associative array](http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/data_types13.html), such as:

```
c[ALPHA] = BETA;
```

If so, you could simply refer to it as:

```
b_t c[a_t];
```

Which means create an associative array `c` who's key is of enums `a_t` and value is of enums `b_t`. You could keep going if you'd like :)

```
typedef enum logic {ALPHA=0, BETA=1} a_t;
typedef enum logic {GAMMA=0, DELTA=1} b_t;
typedef enum logic {BAD_AT=0, GREEK_LETTERS=1} c_t;

c_t my_data_structure[a_t][b_t];

// Assigning a value
my_data_structure[ALPHA][GAMMA] = GREEK_LETTERS;
```

See an example on EDA Playground [here](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/6836).

Also, I think you're slightly misunderstanding the use of `typedef`. It does not exactly describe a set of name-value pairs, rather it gives a new name to a data type. It is the `enum` that is actually creating a 'set of name-value pairs', but I'd clarify that it is essentially assigning identifiers to values. It would help if you could explain the application for a clearer answer.

Comment: Added some clarifying edits to the question. Types `a_t` and `b_t` are immutable. I just need a way to create a third type using these two. And I can't modify existing types.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer, Arun! This works for me. Is the difference here then that we are using unpacked array, as opposed to packed ones in my question? Are there any other side-effects of this?

Comment: So, this is __not__ an unpacked array. This is an associative array (reference the values via keys). The syntax looks similar but indexing is not done via linear numbers as you would with a packed or unpacked array. See the link in my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create one `enum` typedef from another or from a group of others. Some may call that extending an enum. You also cannot have a `enum` with multiple names for the same value.

What you can do is have an associative array with name/value pairs, and join those arrays together.

```
int a[string], b[string], c[string];
initial begin
       a = '{"ALPHA":0, "BETA":1};
       b = '{"GAMMA":0, "DELTA":1};
       c = a;
       foreach(b[s]) c[s]=b[s];
end
```

There are ways of gathering the names of each enumerated type to initialize the associative array as well.

Comment: Added some clarifying edits to the question. Types `a_t` and `b_t` are immutable. I just need a way to create a third type using these two. And I can't modify existing types.

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify that you cannot do what you want directly in SystemVerilog. You cannot have a typedef with duplicate encodings anyway. Use the same or another scrip to generate an associative array of the combined types.

Comment: Do be aware that the performance will degrade when hashing the key. Likely, it won't be significant but it's good to be aware :) Specifically, enums are identifiers for numbers (32-bit I think) but strings are, well, longer than 32-bits and will incur a penalty for access. I do believe though that this is the only sane way to combine them.